# How to change your vote to neutral?

Tags: support, voting

Suppose that *hypothetically* you downvoted a question because it was wrong or it was off-target or *maybe* because the asker wrote it in bad barely comprehensible English without seeming to put any effort in it. Suppose then that *some* moderator comes in to edit the question into actual English and now the question isn't that bad anymore. It's still not worth upvoting, but certainly doesn't deserve a downvote either.

Problem is, if you hit the up arrow to do so, my downvote turns into an upvote. I don't want that!

Is there a way to change your downvote in no vote at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to undo an upvote you have made, click on the upvote arrow.

If you want to undo a downvote you have made, click on the downvote arrow.

Comment: Haven't I already try that ? It goes from +1 directly to -1 and viceversa.

Comment: No - you're clicking on the downvote arrow to undo an upvote. If you want to undo an upvote _you must click on the same upvote arrow._

Comment: Oh. Ok. This doesn't seem logical but ok I get it. +1

Comment: If you are kind to answer,what is the logic behind this behaviour? I don't understand why it's not as I first expected it to be. Only thing I can think of is it works like a toggle mechanism?

Comment: @Fofole Yes, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 5):

You can click the down arrow again to un-vote, canceling out your vote without upvoting.

The same works for upvotes.

Comment: FIRST!!!1!!11!1

Comment: You get my upvote :P

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This already exists. Clicking on the down vote arrow will undo a vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can click the down arrow again. It will cancel the downvote without changing it to an upvote.

Do remember that you can only change your vote up to 5 minutes after you cast it, unless the post is edited. You seem to know that but just writing it here for future visitors :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is click on the downvote again and it will automatically reset your vote. But be sure not to do it after 24 hours!!!!